# Is it possible to do OpenMP reduction over an element of a derived Fortran type?

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, reduction, derived-types

I am trying to adapt a Fortran code (Gfortran) to make use of OpenMP. It is a particle based code where the index of arrays can correspond to particles or pairs. The code uses a derived type to store a number of matrices for each particle. It is very common to come across loops which require the use of a matrix stored in this derived type. This matrix may be accessed by multiple threads. The loop also requires a reduction over an element in this derived type. I currently have to write a temporary array in order to do this reduction and then I set the element of the derived type equal to this temporary reduction array. If not using OpenMP no temporary array is needed.

Question: Is it possible to do a reduction over an element of a derived type? I don't think I can do a reduction over the entire derived type as I need to access some of the elements in the derived type to do work, which means it needs to be SHARED. (From reading the [specification](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) I understand that when using REDUCTION  a private copy of each list item is created.)

Complete minimal working example below. It could be more minimal but I feared that removing more components might over simplify the problem.

```
PROGRAM TEST_OPEN_MP
USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_fortran_env
USE omp_lib

IMPLICIT NONE 

INTEGER,       PARAMETER                      ::  dp = REAL64
INTEGER,       PARAMETER                      ::  ndim=3
INTEGER,       PARAMETER                      ::  no_partic=100000
INTEGER,       PARAMETER                      ::  len_array=1000000
INTEGER                                       ::  k, i, ii, j, jj
INTEGER,       DIMENSION(1:len_array)         ::  pair_i, pair_j
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:len_array)         ::  pair_i_r, pair_j_r
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:no_partic)         ::  V_0 
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim,1:no_partic)  ::  disp, foovec
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim,1:len_array)  ::  dvx 
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:2*ndim,1:len_array)::  vec 
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim)              ::  disp_ij,temp_vec1,temp_vec2
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim,1:ndim)       ::  temp_ten1,temp_ten2
REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:no_partic,1:ndim,1:ndim)::  reduc_ten1
REAL(KIND=dp)                                 ::  sum_check1,sum_check2,cstart,cend

TYPE :: matrix_holder                                                   !<-- The derived type
  REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim,1:ndim)      ::  mat1                 !<-- The first element
  REAL(KIND=dp), DIMENSION(1:ndim,1:ndim)      ::  mat2                 !<-- The second element, etc.
END TYPE matrix_holder

TYPE(matrix_holder), DIMENSION(1:no_partic)    ::  matrix

! Setting "random" values to the arrays
DO k = 1, no_partic
  CALL random_number(matrix(k)%mat1(1:ndim,1:ndim))
  CALL random_number(matrix(k)%mat2(1:ndim,1:ndim))
END DO 
CALL random_number(pair_i_r)
CALL random_number(pair_j_r)
CALL random_number(disp)
CALL random_number(vec)
CALL random_number(dvx)
CALL random_number(V_0)
disp = disp*10.d0
vec = vec*100.d0
dvx = dvx*200.d0
V_0 = V_0*10d0
pair_i = FLOOR(no_partic*pair_i_r)+1
pair_j = FLOOR(no_partic*pair_j_r)+1

! Doing the work 
cstart = omp_get_wtime()
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED) &
!$OMP& PRIVATE(i,j,k,disp_ij,temp_ten1,temp_ten2,temp_vec1,temp_vec2,ii,jj), &
!$OMP& REDUCTION(+:foovec,reduc_ten1), SCHEDULE(static)
DO k= 1, len_array
  i = pair_i(k)
  j = pair_j(k)
  disp_ij(1:ndim) = disp(1:ndim,i)-disp(1:ndim,j)
  temp_vec1 = MATMUL(matrix(i)%mat2(1:ndim,1:ndim),& 
    vec(1:ndim,k))
  temp_vec2 = MATMUL(matrix(j)%mat2(1:ndim,1:ndim),&
    vec(1:ndim,k))
  DO jj=1,ndim
    DO ii = 1,ndim
      temp_ten1(ii,jj) = -disp_ij(ii) * vec(jj,k)
      temp_ten2(ii,jj) = disp_ij(ii) * vec(ndim+jj,k)
    END DO
  END DO
  reduc_ten1(i,1:ndim,1:ndim)=reduc_ten1(i,1:ndim,1:ndim)+temp_ten1*V_0(j) !<--The temporary reduction array
  reduc_ten1(j,1:ndim,1:ndim)=reduc_ten1(j,1:ndim,1:ndim)+temp_ten2*V_0(i)
  foovec(1:ndim,i) = foovec(1:ndim,i) - temp_vec1(1:ndim)*V_0(j)           !<--A generic reduction vector
  foovec(1:ndim,j) = foovec(1:ndim,j) + temp_vec1(1:ndim)*V_0(i)
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
cend = omp_get_wtime()

! Checking the results
sum_check1 = 0.d0 
sum_check2 = 0.d0 
DO i = 1,no_partic
  matrix(i)%mat2(1:ndim,1:ndim)=reduc_ten1(i,1:ndim,1:ndim)                !<--Writing the reduction back to the derived type element
  sum_check1 = sum_check1+SUM(foovec(1:ndim,i))
  sum_check2 = sum_check2+SUM(matrix(i)%mat2(1:ndim,1:ndim))
END DO 
WRITE(*,*) sum_check1, sum_check2, cend-cstart

END PROGRAM TEST_OPEN_MP
```

The only other alternative I can think of would be to remove all the derived types and replace these with large arrays similar to `reduc_ten1` in the example.

Comment: What kind of error did you encounter when you tried to reduce it directly?

Comment: *"I don't think I can do a reduction over the entire derived type as I need to access some of the elements in the derived type to do work, which means it needs to be SHARED."* OpenMP requires the reduced variable to be shared. I don't see a problem here. `reduc_ten1` is shared as well.

Comment: If I try `REDUCTION(+:foovec,matrix%mat2)$` and replace `reduc_ten1(i..)` with `matrix(i)%mat2(i...` in the loop I get _Syntax error in OpenMP variable list_. Is my syntax correct in the list considering that there are `1:no_partic` occurrences of the derived type? Could you please advise how I should write this?

I do not want `mat1` in the derived type to be reduced only `mat2`. Will reducing the entire derived type not reduce this too or only that which is explicitly written within in the loop?

Comment: When testing I find that `!$OMP& REDUCTION(+:foovec,matrix),` results in the compiler error `!$OMP DECLARE REDUCTION + not found for type TYPE(matrix_holder)`. I suppose this means that I would need to declare a reduction first?

Comment: Declared reduction is only if you wish to reduce the whole derived type. You do not want to do that here.

Comment: No I do not. I was naively hoping that I could declare a reduction which would selectively reduce the elements I wanted. I have not declared a reduction before. Do you have any advice as to what I should do to only reduce mat2?

Comment: You cannot use parts of variables in reduction operations. Having `REDUCTION(matrix%mat2)` is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible. At least if I understood your (very complicated for me!) code correctly.

The problem is that you have an array of derived types each have an array. You cannot reference that.

Consider this toy example:

```
  type t
    real :: mat(3)
  end type

  integer, parameter :: n = 100, nk = 1000

  type(t) :: parts(n)

  integer :: i

  real :: array(3,n,nk)

  do k = 1, nk
    array(:,:,nk) = k
  end do

  do i = 1, n
    parts(i)%mat = 0
  end do



  !$omp parallel do reduction(+:parts%mat)
  do k = 1, nk
    do i = 1, n
      parts(i)%mat = parts(i)%mat + array(:,i,nk)
    end do
  end do
  !$omp end parallel do
end
```

Intel Fortran gives a more concrete error:

```
reduction6.f90(23): error #6159: A component cannot be an array if the encompassing structure is an array.   [MAT]
  !$omp parallel do reduction(+:parts%mat)
--------------------------------------^
reduction6.f90(23): error #7656: Subobjects are not allowed in this OpenMP* clause; a named variable must be specified.   [PARTS]
  !$omp parallel do reduction(+:parts%mat)
--------------------------------^
```

---

Remember that it is not even allowed to do this, completely without OpenMP:

```
parts%mat = 0
```

Intel:

```
 reduction6.f90(21): error #6159: A component cannot be an array if the  encompassing structure is an array.   [MAT]
```

gfortran:

```
Error: Two or more part references with nonzero rank must not be specified at (1)
```

You must do this:

```
  do i = 1, n
    parts(i)%mat = 0
  end do
```

The reason for the error reported by Intel above is very similar.

---

Actually no derived type components are allowed in the reduction clause, only variable names can be used. That is the reason for the syntax error reported by gfortran. It does not expect any `%` there. Intel again gives a clearer error message.

But one could make a workaround around that, like passing it to a subroutine and do the reduction there.

Comment: Apologies for the complicated MWE, I need to improve at those. Okay I now need to compare the overhead of making the very large temporary array solely for OpenMP vs. running that part of the code in serial without the temporary array. I was aware that `parts%mat = 0` is not allowed, I was just trying (very poorly) to address your comment.

Comment: Remember, OpenMP also makes temporary arrays. You just don't see them.

Comment: @VladimirF ; Have you seen this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-declare-reduction

Comment: @A2BLK Declared reductions are a new thing from OpenMP (IIRC) 4. But yes, I have heard about it. If you think it will help here you are welcome to post an answer.